# What can I do with a broken orchid stem?

Tags: orchids

I recently bought an orchid for a friend, but a bud stem broke off during transport. I gave out the plant but I still have the stem. The buds aren't very far along.

Can I do something with the stem to give it some life or is it a lost cause?

[image: Broken orchid stem]

Comment: Miracles happen sometimes. I don't know the answer to your question (I'm not well-acquainted with orchid care), but if no one answers, you could always pot it like a cutting and see what happens. Give it low light for two days and really bright, close light after that. You could do tissue culture if you have the means.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt you will get the stem to root, at that stage. Probably the best option would be to put it in a vase and see if it will bloom, as Stephie mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what type of orchid it is, it is hard to predict the chances for success. You could get some rooting powder you can pick up at a gardening supply store and try to stick it in some wet moss and wait to see what happens. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a shoot with blooms it's got chemicals within it to programme it to bloom, and not grow roots. There are unlikely to be nodes along its length which the stem can be cut to length near. If present, cut just below the leaf node, there is just an outside chance it will form roots, but this is highly unlikely. Plant in gritty compost and keep moist. There are unfortunately no leaves on the stem to keep the stem fed via light sources until any roots are formed. 
Alternatively place on window cill in bud vase and enjoy the blooms if they flower.